# Convert SOP to POS in Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-logic

Hi I'm trying to convert [SOP (Sum of Products) to POS (Product of Sums)](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/blog/boolean-logic-sop-and-pos-forms.583/).

The question is like this.

```
ABC +AB'C'+AB'C+ABC'+A'B'C
```

I just want to know some technic how to convert SOP to POS?
I got thus like this but I can't find any more.

```
ABC +AB'C'+AB'C+ABC'+A'B'C
=A(BC +B'C'+B'C+BC')+A'B'C
=A(1+1)+A'B'C
=A+A'B'C'
...
```

Would you please help me ? How to convert this?

Comment: while programmers learnt Boolean Algebra in their first lessons in programming, this question is not directly related to programming so it is Off-Topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as going from disjunctive normal form to conjunctive normal form.  There is a guide on [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214338/how-to-convert-to-conjunctive-normal-form) that highlights doing this with double negation, De Morgan's Law's, and distributive laws.  [Dr Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054911/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51857.html) provides a trick for performing this conversion at the bottom of his reply (it's long so I'll refer you there).